# MySQL IntelliJ IDEA creating function problem in console

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function

I'm having some hard time trying to figure out how to solve this problem. I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to incorporate database into my java programming projects. The problem is that I'm creating a function in the console but it keeps raising a syntax issue: [image]

Can anybody please help me fix this error? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Please add the code to the question - an image of code is not debuggable

Comment: First try _DELIMITER_